# git pull not working,Always display “Receiving objects”

Tags: git, pull

I'm using git, but I can't pull origin master today

```
git pull origin master
remote: Counting objects: 286, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (106/106), done.
receiving objects:  38% (70/184), 196.00 KiB   3 KiB/s
```

I have no idea about that,it is one of my git server,but I can use github and pull origin,help me...

My English is so poor, I hope you don't mind.
  Thanks

Comment: Is it getting stuck at the stage that you have posted? If not, what is the error?

Comment: I got it,It's the problem of my network,thanks Adam Dymitruk.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?